# Which is more secure, admin session token as URL param or cookie?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

If your site has basic user accounts, as well as an admin control panel, it's best practice to have separate sessions for basic users (which can have 'remember me'), and separate sessions for admin access (which you can make forcibly expire after say, 10 minutes of inactivity).

That said, what is a more secure way to handle the **admin** session token - as a parameter in the URL, or as a cookie? (Assume the token is tracked in the database).

What are the security implications of each method? And PHP-specific, can you use the PHP session methods to create multiple session cookies, or do you have to create your own session token cookie?

Comment: @Dagon Hmm but he's specifically asking about the security implications of two alternate ways of making his application

Comment: well if you dont think its both to broad and opinion based, go write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are more secure, especially if you use HTTPS and set the [HTTP only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) and [Secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) flags.

The former stops any JavaScript code from reading the cookie value in case you have any [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerabilities, although if there are any discovered it would be better to secure them to prevent other types of attacks like injecting keyloggers.

The latter makes sure that the cookie is only ever transmitted over a HTTPS connection. Without it a [MITM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacker could redirect another request to a HTTP website to `http://www.example.com` (where `example.com` is your website) and then intercept the session cookie that your site has set.

Storing Session IDs in URLs is a bad idea as they are stored in browser history, they will be logged by default (on proxies and on the server) and they can be leaked by the [`referer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header if an admin follows a link from your site to elsewhere (or even if your admin site references an external image).

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies sent over https. This is more secure that a standard cookie and much more secure than using URL params.
For more details take a look at the php documentation at php.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are usually a more secure choice.

Url params go into logs. Especially GET parameters are logged by default in many web/application servers. In addition an URL param can leak in many unexpected ways. Do you know about the leakage that may happen with the Referer header? This is just one example https://isc.sans.edu/diary/When+does+your+browser+send+a+%22Referer%22+header+(or+not)%3F/16433 it is a minor vulnerability mostly, but it happens.